# listbox with checkbox, with select All option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, kendo-ui

This is the type of listbox, I am looking for a jquery plugin, or something in Jquery or Kendo UI. I searched a lot but in vain. I need a listbox, where i bind to a datasource. The items in listbox should have checkbox, allowing user to check/uncheck. I also want an option of All item in the list, enabling user to select all items in listbox or unselect all items in listbox. Have u come across any plugin like that?

[image: Listbox with checkbox option to select all]

Answer (score 3):

I have used this plugin before, and it more or less does what you describe:

http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Much nicer than a list box in my opinion, and simply generates automatically off a select element.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using jqWidjects

http://www.jqwidgets.com/listbox-with-checkboxes/

they have opensource and paid APIs. see which one will best fit to your needs

if you want to stick to plugins you mentioned in your question then you can try kendo multiselect custom template

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/multiselect/template.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen: http://joelanman.com/2009/03/simple-multiple-selection-with-checkbox-lists-and-jquery/?
It seems to do the trick without a plug in.